# Application Modeller - Java Application using batch file

Tags: blueprism

I have a batch file that starts a Java application which I want to spy in the application modeller. The Java option in blue prism requires executable jar which is not available in my case. The batch file contains some logic based on which the application is started so it must be started from batch file only.

Should I use Windows option in application modeller to point to cmd.exe and configure the batch file.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 4 possible solutions:

1. Use “Utility – Environment” VBO & “Start Process” action. It has two input parameters: Application (full path to batch script file) & Arguments (provide if necessary, it could be e.g. country code or environment type)
2. Using Surface Automation techniques start batch script the same way as human user would
3. Use code stage & Process.Start Method more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2
4. Create object to automate command line and replicate steps from script

I suggest to try solutions 1 & 2 as they don’t require additional scripting/coding knowledge.